# Render XML in jsp from Custom Tag

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jstl

I have custom tag in which I am getting the content of XML files and storing them in Strings and trying to render on jsp. Below is some code snapshot.

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            String final_str="";
            while (dis.available() != 0) {
                String currentLine=dis.readLine();
                System.out.println(currentLine);
                final_str += currentLine + "\n";
            }
            logger.info(final_str);
            pageContext.setAttribute("sitemap",final_str);
```

What i use on jsp.

```
<c:out value = "${sitemap}" />
```

How can I render the XML in jsp? My log file display the XML but not render properly on browser. As shown.[image]

Comment: Tidied up some grammatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

> bis.toString()
>   will definitely return an object.
>   You can probably do this,

```
dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
String final_str="";
while (dis.available() != 0) {  
        String currentLine=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println(currentLine);
        final_str + = currentLine + "\n";
}
```

The above code will print all lines in your input stream, you can store it into a string & return it with

```
pageContext.setAttribute("sitemap",final_str);
```

**UPDATE**
This function takes a normal xml String and formats the string (indent)

```
public static String formatXSD(String xmlString) {
        try {
            Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);

            return xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, there are two things here. First when XML render then "/n" new line not working. Second it display the value of XML tags only. Tag itself not appear.

Comment: Can you please post the result

Comment: Problem got solved by using escapeXML in cout tag, But do you have any idea how to perform indentation of xml in jsp

Comment: Oh Good! 
I don't have an idea of how to indent XML in **JSP**, but I know how to do it java